# Remove ns1 prefix with XSLT for SoapEnvelope

Tags: xslt, soap, prefix, envelope

Good afternoon,

I need to remove ns1 prefix with XSLT for SoapEnvelope

I have the following XML below:

```
<ns1:mt_BuscarOrdemServico_Request xmlns:ns1="http://www.supergasbras.com.br/service/BuscarOrdemServico">
   <ordemServico>
      <codigo>175811</codigo>
      <codigoOrdemServico>7462242</codigoOrdemServico>
   </ordemServico>
</ns1:mt_BuscarOrdemServico_Request>
```

I need to create a soap envelope to send my XML file to a webservice with the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:esb="http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <esb:buscaOrdemServico>
         <ordemServico xmlns:ns1="http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb">
            <codigo>11</codigo>
            <codigoOrdemServico>74</codigoOrdemServico>
         </ordemServico>
      </esb:buscaOrdemServico>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope
```

I am using the following XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:esb="http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb">
         <soapenv:Header>
         </soapenv:Header>
         <soapenv:Body>
             <esb:buscaOrdemServico>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
             </esb:buscaOrdemServico>
         </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

But with this XSLT code I am getting the following result:
```

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:esb="http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <esb:buscaOrdemServico>
         <ns1:ordemServico xmlns:ns1="http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb">
            <codigo>11</codigo>
            <codigoOrdemServico>74</codigoOrdemServico>
         </ns1:ordemServico>
      </esb:buscaOrdemServico>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope
```

Can you help me to remove the prefix ns1?

Comment: 1. The result you show is very different from the result I get then applying your XSLT to the given XML. -- 2. Why do you need the `xmlns:ns1="http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb` declaration in the result you want to get? It is not used anywhere.

Comment: Good night,
I agree. It is not necessary to have xmlns: ns1 = "http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb.

However I need to remove the prefix ns1:

My final XML should be:

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:esb="http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <esb:buscaOrdemServico>
         <ordemServico>
            <codigo>11</codigo>
            <codigoOrdemServico>74</codigoOrdemServico>
         </ns1:ordemServico>
      </esb:buscaOrdemServico>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope

Comment: Please do not post code in comments; edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a result that is semantically identical to the one you want using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:esb="http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <esb:buscaOrdemServico>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*/ordemServico"/>
             </esb:buscaOrdemServico>
         </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, copying a node in XSLT 1.0 also copies the namespaces in scope for that node. Therefore, the result will include a redundant namespace declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:esb="http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <esb:buscaOrdemServico>
      <ordemServico xmlns:ns1="http://www.supergasbras.com.br/service/BuscarOrdemServico">
        <codigo>175811</codigo>
        <codigoOrdemServico>7462242</codigoOrdemServico>
      </ordemServico>
    </esb:buscaOrdemServico>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This *should* not pose a problem for the receiving application. If it does, you can remove it by avoiding copying altogether - for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:esb="http://servicos.embratec.com.br/esb">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <esb:buscaOrdemServico>
                <ordemServico>
                    <codigo>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*/ordemServico/codigo"/>
                    </codigo>
                    <codigoOrdemServico>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*/ordemServico/codigoOrdemServico"/>
                    </codigoOrdemServico>
                </ordemServico>
             </esb:buscaOrdemServico>
         </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```